# ERROR SQLite foreign key mismatch

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

he intentado varias cosas para conseguir crear una base de datos relacional en SQLite, pero no consigo eliminar o editar algún registro en la base de datos sin recibir el mismo error:

***foreign key mismatch "Test" - referencing "Allgemeine Info" (DELETE FROM "main"."Allgemeine Info" WHERE *rowid* in ('1');)***

Así he creado las tablas:

````
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE "Allgemeine Info" (
    "ID"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Name"  STRING,
    "Ort"   STRING,
    "PLZ"   STRING,
    "Strasse"   STRING,
    "Nummer"    STRING,
    "Datum" STRING,
    "Ersteller" STRING,
    "Am"    STRING,
    "Geändert von"  STRING,
    "Geändert am"   STRING,
    "Betreiber" STRING,
    "Ortsnamen" STRING,
    "Hausnummer"    STRING,
    "Raumnummer"    STRING,
    "Ansprechpartner"   STRING,
    "Telefon1"  STRING,
    "Telefon2"  STRING,
    "Email" STRING,
    "GPS"   STRING,
    "ZPB"   STRING NOT NULL,
    "ZPB(1-13)" STRING,
    "ZPBOrt(14-16)" STRING,
    "Projektzuordnung"  STRING,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID           INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    ZPB_ref      STRING NOT NULL,
    Adresse      STRING DEFAULT "",
    Seriennummer STRING DEFAULT "",
    ZPB          STRING DEFAULT "", 
    CONSTRAINT "T1" FOREIGN KEY (ZPB_ref) REFERENCES [Allgemeine Info] (ZPB) ON DELETE CASCADE
);```
````

Comment: creo que te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208245/what-is-causing-foreign-key-mismatch-error

Comment: Parece que la foreign key ZPB_ref no le está gustando porque no la encuentra en tu tabla "Allgemeine Info". Como no la encuentra, te salta el error.